# Principles of Counting Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I currently have the following as an assignment question:

In a group of 123 students, the number taking Calculus is 3 times
more than the number taking Discrete Math. 72 students take exactly one of
these subjects and 23 are taking neither course. **How many students are taking
Discrete Math? How many are taking Calculus?**

I understand that

> |Students| = 123
>
> |Calculus| = 3 * |Discrete|
>
> 72 = |Calculus' or Discrete'|
>
> 23 = |Students / (Calculus ∪ Discrete)|

Now I understand **|C ∪ D| = |C| + |D| - |A ∩ B|**, but how do I apply that principles here to get the answer for students taking Discrete Math and Calculus?

Comment: HINT Start with the clue that 23 take neither.  So, how many students take one or both? Then use the first clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ students are taking both courses, $B$ students are taking only discrete math, $C$ students are taking only calculus and $D$ students are taking neither. It is quite obvious, that the number of students who took calculus is $A + C$ and of the ones, who took discrete mathematics is $A + B$. Thus your question becomes a system of linear equations:

$$A + B + C + D = 123$$
$$A + C = 3A + 3B$$
$$B + C = 72$$
$$D = 23$$

Its solution is:

$$A = 28$$
$$B = 4$$
$$C = 68$$
$$D = 23$$

And that means, that $A + C = 28 + 68 = 96$ students are taking calculus and $A + B = 28 + 4 = 32$ are taking discrete mathematics.